# DbContext not updating but DB is

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an MVC 5 data first app that I've been helping with. I made it use a filter to determine if the AD user is allowed certain functionality (via decorating methods/classes).

However, after changing a user's info in the db, the filter's context still has the old info for that user. The user 'edit' page keeps correct info though. Strange. This is happening just in the filter, not in any controller.

Here's the filter:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    if (!base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext)) return false;

    // Get the groups for this authorization (from the decoration attribute)
    var groups = Groups.Split(',').ToList();

    var userDisplayName = string.Empty;

    using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
    {
        // Verify that the user is in the given AD group (if any)
        var context = new PrincipalContext(
            ContextType.Domain);

        var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
            context,
            IdentityType.SamAccountName,
            httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

        userDisplayName = userPrincipal.DisplayName;
    }

    // check for UserRoles for this 
    var user = _varDB.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userDisplayName); //< Here is where it gets stale info...
    IList<UserRole> usersRoles = new List<UserRole>();
    if (user != null)
    {
        usersRoles = user.UserRoles.ToList();
    }

    // determine if the user is allowed to see this controller/page
    foreach (var ur in usersRoles)
    {
        if (groups.Contains(ur.RoleName))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

On the UserController, if I manually change the db, and refresh the page, I see the changes. But in this filter, if I change the data, it never changes until I recycle the app pool.

fyi, the top of the class goes like this:

```
public class AuthorizeByDbRoleAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{       
    private static ExtVariablesEntities _varDB = new ExtVariablesEntities();
}
```

If this filter doesn't get the updated user info, it can't keep users out of or let them use functionality if changed and the app pool isn't recycled.

Comment: This is how static works....  Static exists for the duration of the Application Domain.  I would never recommend creating an EF Context like this, nor storing it static-ally, you just asking for problems (which you are not realizing).

Comment: FYI, you can rewrite your foreach to this:  return userRoles.Any(x => groups.Contains(x.RoleName));  (Untested)

Comment: yes I removed the 'static' attribute. I was in a copy/paste frenzy. Not sure why the previous dev set that as static. However, it still doesn't update. My co-worker mentioned that since it is a filter it might have a different context and therefore not getting updates

Comment: you are not getting how a DbContext works. the DbContext won't load updated entities from Db every now and then, it will just mirror its contents to match the db when calling savechanges. When you want your context to be updated, issue database calls.

Comment: I understand all that. The problem was, that in a class that inherits from 'AuthorizeAttribute', it's not disposing/recreating the context page to page. I wound up wrapping the logic in a 'using' for the context. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that a class that inherits from AuthorizeAttribute (or any attribute I believe) the class doesn't dispose of the context. I wound up wrapping the logic in a using like this:

```
 using (ExtVariablesEntities _varDB = new ExtVariablesEntities())
        {
            // check for UserRoles for this 
            var user = _varDB.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userDisplayName);

            IList<UserRole> usersRoles = new List<UserRole>();
            if (user != null)
            {
                usersRoles = user.UserRoles.ToList();
            }

            // determine if the user is allowed to see this controller/page
            foreach (var ur in usersRoles)
            {
                if (groups.Contains(ur.RoleName))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
```

This was the context get created each time this class method is hit.